# Guarda consulta en tabla temporal con procedimientos almacenados SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prueba 
@pal varchar(45)
as
CREATE TABLE #param(folio int,tit varchar(max),descr varchar(max))
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO #param SELECT * from post where titulo=@pal
SELECT * FROM #param;
go
```

y así lo invoco

```
exec prueba @pal="aquamarina"
```

y quiero que el resultado de ese select se guarde en la tabla temporal que creé.

Comment: Se puede hacer pero con lo que tienes no hay razon para hacerlo. tienes que recordar que la tabla temporal no existe fuera del procedimiento

Comment: si, pero es que no necesito que exista esa tabla en la base de datos, solo necesito almacenar resultados deuna consulta

Comment: Entonces si funccionara. Tambien considera usar un table variable. El decision de cual usar se base en la cantidad de datos

Comment: Pero quiero saber si esta bien esta línea de código SQL "INSERT INTO #param SELECT * from post where titulo=@pal", porque cuando ejecuto el procedimiento me manda error

Comment: La línea esta bien siempre que la tabla post tenga los mismos campos y orden que la temporal #param

Comment: Si, tiene los mismos campos, pero en la linea del insert marca estos errores The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Comment: El problema entonces es el parámetro `@pal`, deberías hacer `WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, título) = @pal`

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer buscas esto,

```
insert into TU_TABLA_TEMPRAL exec prueba @pal="aquamarina"
```

Tener en cuenta:

> Los campos que retorna el procedimiento, deben ser los mismos de tu TU_TABLA_TEMPORAL (me refiero a la misma cantidad de columnas y deben de coincidir los tipos de datos)

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que intentas hacer entiendo que es esto:

Tienes un Sp que crea y llena una tabla temporal

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_prueba 
AS
    CREATE TABLE #Prueba(id int)
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO #Prueba (id) VALUES (1)

RETURN 0
```

Luego afuera de la tabla temporal intentas recuperar los datos de la siguiente forma

```
EXEC sp_prueba
SELECT * FROM #Prueba;
```

Esto te debería dar un error `Invalid object name '#Prueba'` por que efectivamente la tabla temporal solo existe dentro del Sp. Normalmente esto se resuelve llevando la creación de la temporal afuera del Sp.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_prueba 
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO #Prueba (id) VALUES (1)

RETURN 0
```

Y al invocar lo haces así

```
CREATE TABLE #Prueba(id int)
EXEC sp_prueba
SELECT * FROM #Prueba;
```

Y ahora si debiera funcionar

Comment: Pero quiero que la tabla temporal este dentro del SP

Comment: Ya actualicé la pregunta

Comment: Las temporales creadas dentro de un sp solo "viven" dentro del mismo incluso si no se "dropean" explícitamente. Podrías hacer que el Sp devuelva el SELECT de la temporal y afuera del mismo lo capturas en otra tabla, no es lo ideal por que hay un límite de inserts anidados en SQL SEVER.

Comment: Si de hecho capturo al final el resultado del select de la tabla temporal, pero es que mi problema es que no se inserta la consulta que estoy haciendo en la tabla temporal

Answer (score 0):

Hola mira te copio un procedimiento que tuve que hacer en donde trabajo con temporal, espero te sirva, quedo atento a tus dudas. ( puse solo la parte de la consulta par ano escribir el codigo de creacion del sp)

```
CREATE TABLE #TMPRECOMPRA (ID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1),facId BIGINT)
            INSERT INTO #TMPRECOMPRA
            SELECT V.FacId 
            FROM FIP_Venta V 
            INNER JOIN FACTURAS F ON F.facID= V.facID 
            WHERE estado = @Estado

                    SELECT   T.facID
                    ,F.estado 'Estado'
                    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,F.fecha_vencimiento,103) 'fecha_vencimiento'
                    ,CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,0),F.valor_documento)  'valor_rescate'
                    ,DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),F.fecha_vencimiento) 'Dias_por_vencer'
                    ,ROUND(CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,0),F.valor_documento)-(CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,0),F.valor_documento)/(((v.ven_tasa_captacion/100/30)*(DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),F.fecha_vencimiento)))+1)),0) 'Interes_por_recuperar'
                    ,CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,0),F.valor_documento) - ROUND(CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,0),F.valor_documento)-(CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,0),F.valor_documento)/(((v.ven_tasa_captacion/100/30)*(DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),F.fecha_vencimiento)))+1)),0) 'Valor_recompra'
                    ,DATEDIFF(DAY,[dbo].[fnFechaAnteriorHabil](F.fecha_vencimiento), F.fecha_vencimiento)  as 'dias reliq'
                    ,ISNULL(R.Folio_Recompra, '') AS Folio_Recompra
                    FROM #TMPRECOMPRA as T
                    INNER JOIN fip_venta v on v.facID=t.facId
                    INNER JOIN Facturas as F ON t.facId=f.facID
                    LEFT  JOIN  FIP_Recompra R ON T.facID= R.facID
                    WHERE T.ID BETWEEN  CAST(ISNULL(@RegIni, 0) AS VARCHAR)  AND  CAST(ISNULL(@RegFin, 0) AS VARCHAR)



            DROP TABLE #TMPRECOMPRA

        END
```